# DockPanel disable close button

Tags: .net, dockpanel-suite

I am using DockPanel suite. I need to disable the Close button of the DockPanel. I found that:

```
dockPanel1.CloseButtonVisible = false;
```

will remove close button. But in my dockpanel there is no property called CloseButtonVisible. So how do I remove close button?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the DevExpress components ?

If so you should look for:

```
   myDockPanelName.Options.ShowCloseButton = False;
```

Answer (score 1):

This method is not present on `DockPanel`. It is on the `DockContent` so this will work:

```
content1.CloseButtonVisible = false;
```